# Creating a real time notification from android service

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating an application which shows the notification as soon as I post a new post on wordpress site.

Now the notification is generated as soon as I put a post on the wordpress site.

But after 40-45 minutes the app gets crashed and gets killed in the background with the following error:-

[the error that showed after the app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiTsJ.png)

I have tried many solutions none of it worked.
I don't want to use `firebase` for the notification.

I have to fetch the data in real time from the wordpress and then create the notification.

This is the following code for generating the notification:-

private void setupNotificationListener(){

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            flag=1;
            //System.out.println(flag);
            gson = new Gson();
            list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
            postTitle = new String[list.size()];
            postContent=new String[list.size()];

            System.out.println("shiv class:"+list.size());
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i) {
                mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(i);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");
                postContent[i] = (String) mapContent.get("rendered");
            }
            if(!alreadyNotified(postTitle[0])){
                Log.d("not notified","");
                createNotif(postContent[0],postTitle[0]);
                saveNotificationKey(postTitle[0]);
            }else{
                System.out.print("already notified");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("Error","Error");
        }
    });

    rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NotifierService.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
    NotifierService.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are creating multiple thread in background to fetch your new post ! This error occurs due to low memory ! At what interval you are checking for new post ?

Comment: This is the code that i am writing

Comment: Post your current code !

Comment: From where you are calling this  setupNotificationListener() method ?

Comment: from a timer in every 5 seconds

Comment: Increase that time 5 seconds to 40 or 60 seconds !!

Comment: okay I have done that just testing the app, is the code for setupNotificationListener() correct??

Comment: Its better that you count total post and store that count and check it again ! if count increase then throw notification with content and fetch only latest 1 post details ! why you are fetching all post details ??

Comment: so i will just fetch the latest post!

Comment: Yes ! this way you can save phone battery and you won't face out of memory error again !!!

Comment: the app got killed after some time!!

Comment: Its Better to create service and call that service with AlarmManager from your activity!

Comment: I have used alarm manager in ontaskremoved method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the requestQueue from a timer, so every 5 seconds. And within your executed code you create always a new request queue. This won't work you should keep the requestQueue as final global variable and create it only once in your constructor.

```
public class NotifierService extends Service {
    private final RequestQueue rQueue;

    NotifierService() {
        this.rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    private void setupNotificationListener() {
        // do your request handling
    }
}
```

The OutOfMemoryError might occur because you create so many objects which are not correctly garbage collected

Comment: so here i just need to add the request to the queue !                           rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NotifierService.this);   this line has to be written only once.  right?

Comment: it's giving a null pointer exception                                                         Unable to instantiate service .NotifierService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference