# How to empty volley requestqueue in android

Tags: android, android-volley

```
private void setupNotificationListener(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            flag=1;
            //System.out.println(flag);
            Map<String,Object> mapPost, mapContent;
            Map<String,Object> mapTitle;

            gson = new Gson();
            list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
            postTitle = new String();
            postContent=new String();


            System.out.println("shiv class:"+list.size());
            mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(0);
            mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
            postTitle = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
            mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");
            postContent = (String) mapContent.get("rendered");

            if(!alreadyNotified(postTitle)){
                Log.d("not notified","");
                createNotif(postContent,postTitle);
                saveNotificationKey(postTitle);
            }else{
                System.out.print("already notified");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("Error","Error");
        }
    });

    rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NotifierService.this);
    rQueue.add(request);

    NotifierService.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
}
```

this is my whole function in which I am sending the volley request and parsing the json from the url.
Now I want to fetch the json every minute without increasing the requestqueue.
Is there any way to empty the requestqueue ??

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/a/19149302/3734116

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel All Volley Requests Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774667/cancel-all-volley-requests-android)

Comment: i have used it t didn't work .  can u tell me where to write that cancel code in the above function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cancel all request as soon as an error has occurred:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String s) {
        //....
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        //....
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
             @Override
             public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
                 return true;
             }
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to cancel all request as soon as you leave your activity put the cancel code into you onStop method.
You should do this as otherwise you would operate in an activity which is probably already finished and during the job execution it would possibly create a memory leak

Comment: what m trying to do is create a notification from this json parsing as soon as i get the new post.  but the app crashes after 24 hrs i think it's because the memory is finished.  will the above solution be apt for that workflow which I want?

Comment: why cancel it then? As soon as the new post has arrived this job is deleted from the queue, you don't have to do it manually

Comment: but why does the app crash see   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297210/creating-a-real-time-notification-from-android-service    this is the error I am getting when app crashes